# Discord.js starting two bots

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just made a command handler, but for some reason it starts two bots (I used the same commands I used before, I just put them inro a different file). I tried generating new token but that did not help. I rebooted my pc but nothing. This is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands/").filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);

  client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready!");
  });

  client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
      case "kick":
        client.commands.get("kick").execute(message, args);
        break;

      case "serverinfo":
        client.commands.get("serverinfo").execute(message, args);
        break;
    }
  });

  client.login(token);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a separate bot with the same prefix?

Comment: No, this is my only one. And now if I put the code back to the main file it doesn't work either as it used to.

Comment: I think it's because you're using the events inside the `for loop`, try putting you events and `client.login()` outside the `for loop`, above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands were in the for loop.